SaveAs(memoryStream) Takes too long
I have a serious problem with this code:
ajaxAuthenticator.Authenticate();

XLWorkbook template = templateBuilder.BuildTemplate();

using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    template.SaveAs(memoryStream);
    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}

The problem is in this line
template.SaveAs(memoryStream);

It is taking something like 6 minutes for this line!
I search all around and didnt find any alternatives hope one of you will have.

What library are you using, how much data is there and why save to a memory stream? If the library is slow and you try to store 1M rows, yes, this process will be slow. Copying the contents of MemoryStream's buffer to another array will also be slow

If the library you use actually uses Excel Interop, then everything will be slow, as every operation is an inter-process call, 100s of times slower than a local method call. There are several libraries that generate Excel files without requiring Excel, from the full featured EPPlus to the more restricted but 10 times faster and more memory efficient SylvanXlsx. You'll find benchmarks comparing all of them here

You'll notice xlw isn't included.  It's rarely used with just 4K downloads at NuGet and now that I look at it, not even suitable for Excel generation. And the Github repo shows it's essentially abandoned

@PanagiotisKanavos The code is someone else's I'm trying to optimize it.
It is about 4 sheets, one has 80K rows and the rest is around 20 rows.
I tried to understand what you wrote in your answer, but I could not understand how to implement what you wrote.
I work with an aspx page and write the code in C#.

@PanagiotisKanavos I tried this too but it takes more time:
ajaxAuthenticator.Authenticate();     XLWorkbook template = templateBuilder.BuildTemplate();     string tempFolderPath = Path.GetTempPath();     string fileName = "TempTemplate.xlsx";     string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(tempFolderPath, fileName);     try     {         template.SaveAs(tempFilePath);         byte[] byteTemplate=File.ReadAllBytes(tempFilePath);         return byteTemplate;     }     finally     {         if (File.Exists(tempFilePath))         {             File.Delete(tempFilePath);         }     }
